# Position Elements within a flex container with predefined widths using tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am currently having trouble with styling a card component using tailwind CSS.

[image]

As you cann see, the prices are not aligned properly - how can I make it aligned?

My current code for the Cards

```
<div onClick={deleteItem} className="flex flex-row justify-center">
      <div className="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
        <div>
          <p>{props.itemName}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>{props.itemPrice} €</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>X</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be, two wrap the `itemPrice` and `X` div in another div and give it the class `flex`.
This way would would have two divs, one on the very left, containing the item name, and one on the very right, containing the item price and the x button right next to each other.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
    <div>
      <p>{props.itemName}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="flex space-x-4">
        <p>{props.itemPrice} €</p>
        <div>
          <p>X</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is flex items by default have a `flex-basis: auto` which means that the item should use its main size initially and `flex-grow: 0`, which means don't grow or don't take the available space. And what separates them is `justify-between` by its parent container.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
    <div class="bg-red-500">
      <p>Salmon Sushi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">
      <p>18.99 €</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500">
      <p>X</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
    <div class="bg-red-500">
      <p>pizza</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">
      <p>10.5 €</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500">
      <p>X</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To fix this we will just let the last item which is the `X` parent container use its initial main size (size can also be defined), then we will distribute the free available space to the first two `div` containers or items equally.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
    <div class="basis-0 grow bg-red-500">
      <p class="">Salmon Sushi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="basis-0 grow bg-green-500">
      <p>18.99 €</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500">
      <p>X</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
    <div class="basis-0 grow">
      <p>pizza</p>
    </div>
    <div class="basis-0 grow">
      <p>10.5 €</p>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <p>X</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By giving `flex-basis: 0px;` along with the `flex-grow: 1` we are able to distribute the available spaces equally.

**Additional:** For lengthy texts.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
    <div class="min-w-0 basis-0 grow whitespace-nowrap bg-red-500">
      <p class="truncate">Salmon Sushiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</p>
    </div>
    <div class="min-w-0 basis-0 grow whitespace-nowrap bg-green-500">
      <p class="truncate">18.99 €€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500">
      <p>X</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 w-10/12 m-1 rounded p-1 flex justify-between">
    <div class="basis-0 grow">
      <p>pizza</p>
    </div>
    <div class="basis-0 grow">
      <p>10.5 €</p>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <p>X</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```